# AngularJS ng-table - Rest call in method - how do I update the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ngtable

i got a little problem.
I use ng-table for my table. Now I want to use a kind of filtering which is done in the backend. I use typescript, so my constructor looks like this:

```
public constructor(private restService:restService){
this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({page: 1, count: 50}, {
  getData:  function(x) { 
    return  restService.getPage(x.count(),x.page()).then((data)=> {
   // do stuff
    return data.content;
}); } });
```

Now I got a dropdown list in my HTML and on ng-change I call my method which makes a rest call with the filter as queryParam and returns the objects:

```
private methodA(){
restService.getPage(x.filter).then((data)=>{
//
});
```

My ng-table in the HTML file is like this:

```
 <table ng-table="vm.tableParams" >
 <tr ng-repeat-start="x in $data track by x.id">
 ... </tr></table>
```

My question is now: where do I have to put the objects which methodA returns so that it is in $data in the HTLM? Do I have to use a new NgTableParams object? If so, how can I do this as he only knows NgTableParams in the constructor?

cliffnotes: I have a rest call in a method (other than the constructor). Where do I have to put the returnValue in order to see them in the HTML?

I hope you understood my problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your methodA() you need to assign `data` to a variable and set it as your data within your table.  You should also use a callback function if the `http` fails

```
private methodA(){
restService.getPage(x.filter).success(function (data){
$scope.myData = data;
}, function (error) {
        alert("Error Retrieving Data");
        $q.reject(error);
});
```

then reference your `$scope.myData` in your HTML:

```
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" >
<tr ng-repeat-start="x in myData track by x.id">
... </tr></table>
```

you do not need the `$` when referencing anything on the scope from your HTML